# No route matches {:action=>"schedule", :controller=>"users"}

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes

I have a weird problem : I get the following error after signing in and trying to go back home following  URL `localhost:3000/`

" No route matches {:action=>"schedule", :controller=>"users"} "

Here is routes.rb :

```
Ikky::Application.routes.draw do
  root to: 'static_pages#home'

  resources :users do
    member do
      get 'schedule'
    end
  end
```

`rake routes` return the following :

```
         root        /                             static_pages#home
schedule_user GET    /users/:id/schedule(.:format) users#schedule
        users GET    /users(.:format)              users#index
              POST   /users(.:format)              users#create
[...]
```

The issue appeared when introducing my schedule_user route.

Here is my users_controller :

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

before_filter :signed_in_user, only: [:index, :edit, :update, :destroy, :schedule]
before_filter :correct_user,   only: [:edit, :update]
before_filter :admin_user,     only: :destroy

  def schedule
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @spots = @user.spots.paginate(page: params[:page])
    @spot = current_user.spots.build if signed_in?
  end
```

And here is the static_pages_controller :

```
class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController

  def home
    @spot = current_user.spots.build if signed_in?
  end
```

Here is the partial shared/user_info :

```
<a href="<%= user_path(current_user) %>">

  <%= gravatar_for current_user, size: 52 %>
</a>
<h1>
  <%= current_user.name %>
</h1>
<span>
  <%= link_to "view my profile", current_user %>
</span>
<span>
  <%= pluralize(current_user.spots.count, "spots") %>
</span>
```

Thank you for your help!

P.S : I am a beginner so sorry if my code is a mess...

Comment: Is there any link to users/schedule in /static_pages/home view?

Comment: No link to users/schedule, only a partial to the user info : `  <% if signed_in? %>
<%= render 'shared/user_info' %>  <% else %>
`

Comment: Normally it will happen if we put member path without id. Eg: link_to "A", 'users/schedule' or schedule_user_path.

Comment: mmh. so how can I fix that?

Comment: can you share the 'shared/user_info' view. Or currect the link like  'users/#{user.id}/schedule' or schedule_user_path(user.id)

Comment: please have a look above

Comment: Thanks for sharing the view. But i didn't find any link to users/schedule. Where you are using this link. I just want to see that link in view. Or you can correct your self with above solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally it will happen if we put `member` path without `id`. Eg: `link_to "A", 'users/schedule' or schedule_user_path`.

Solve this problem by correcting the link to `'users/#{user.id}/schedule'` or `schedule_user_path(user.id)`